# How to use inline modifiers in C# regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How do I use the inline modifiers instead of `RegexOptions.Option`?

For example:

```
Regex MyRegex = new Regex(@"[a-z]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

How do I rewrite this using the inline character `i`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use inline modifiers as follows:

```
// case insensitive match
Regex MyRegex = new Regex(@"(?i)[a-z]+");  // case insensitive match
```

or, inverse the meaning of the modifier by adding a minus-sign:

```
// case sensitive match
Regex MyRegex = new Regex(@"(?-i)[a-z]+");  // case sensitive match
```

or, switch them on and off:

```
// case sensitive, then case-insensitive match
Regex MyRegex = new Regex(@"(?-i)[a-z]+(?i)[k-n]+");
```

Alternatively, you can use the *mode-modifier span* syntax using a colon `:` and a grouping parenthesis, which scopes the modifier to only that group:

```
// case sensitive, then case-insensitive match
Regex MyRegex = new Regex(@"(?-i:[a-z]+)(?i:[k-n]+)");
```

You can use multiple modifiers in one go like this `(?is-m:text)`, or after another, if you find that clearer `(?i)(?s)(?-m)text` (I don't). When you use the on/off switching syntax, be aware that the modifier works till the next switch, or the end of the regex. Conversely, using the mode-modified spans, after the span the default behavior will apply.

Finally: [the allowed modifiers in .NET are](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) (use a minus to invert the mode):

`x` allow whitespace and comments
`s` single-line mode
`m` multi-line mode
`i` case insensitivity
`n` only allow explicit capture (.NET specific)

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to use multiple modifiers, I just do `(?imsx)` instead of `(?i)`, for example?

Comment: @aillyn, yes, exactly

Answer (score 8):

Use it in this manner:

```
Regex MyRegex = new Regex(@"(?i:[a-z]+)");
```

Prefix the inline option to your pattern with `(?<option>:<pattern>)`. In this case the option is "i" for IgnoreCase.

By specifying a colon above you are setting the option to just that pattern. To make the option apply to the entire pattern you may set it in the beginning on its own:

```
@"(?i)[a-z]+"
```

It is also possible to use multiple options and turn them on and off:

```
// On: IgnoreCase, ExplicitCapture. Off: IgnorePatternWhitespace
@"(?in-x)[a-z]+"
```

This allows for flexibility in a pattern to enable/disable options at different points of a regex that isn't possible when using the `RegexOptions` on the entire pattern.

Here is a slightly in-depth example. I encourage you to play with it to understand when the options are taking effect.

```
string input = "H2O (water) is named Dihydrogen Monoxide or Hydrogen Hydroxide. The H represents a hydrogen atom, and O is an Oxide atom.";

// n = explicit captures
// x = ignore pattern whitespace
// -i = remove ignorecase option
string pattern = @"di?(?nx-i) ( hydrogen ) | oxide";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine("Total Matches: " + matches.Count);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match: {0} - Groups: {1}", match.Value, match.Groups[1].Captures.Count);
}

Console.WriteLine();

// n = explicit captures
// x = ignore pattern whitespace
// -i = remove ignorecase option
// -x = remove ignore pattern whitespace
pattern = @"di?(?nx-i) (?<H> hydrogen ) (?-x)|oxide";
matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine("Total Matches: " + matches.Count);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match: {0} - Groups: {1}", match.Value, match.Groups["H"].Captures.Count);
}
```

The output for the above is:

```
Total Matches: 3
Match: Dihydrogen - Groups: 0
Match: oxide - Groups: 0
Match: oxide - Groups: 0

Total Matches: 3
Match: Dihydrogen - Groups: 1
Match: oxide - Groups: 0
Match: oxide - Groups: 0
```

In both patterns `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is used which allows "di" to be case insensitive and thus match "Dihydrogen" (capital D). Since explicit capturing is on, the first example fails to have any groups for `( hydrogen )` since it doesn't use a named group, which is the requirement for explicit capturing. The second pattern does have 1 group since it uses `(?<H> hydrogen )`.

Next, notice that the second pattern is modified to use `(?-x)|oxide` at the end. Since *IgnorePatternWhitespace* is disabled after the hydrogen capture, the remainder of the pattern must be correctly formed by not having additional whitespace (compare with the first pattern) until `(?x)` is turned on later in the pattern. This serves no real purpose but just shows an in-depth usage of inline options to demonstrate when they actually kick in.