# A Question on group matches in regex

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex

`\.((jpg)|(gif)|(jpeg)|(png)|(doc)|(docx)|(pdf)|(zip)|(rar))$` that's the regex i am testing in Regex Hero. test string is `Sprite.png` Just 2 simple questions

1. Matches show as 2 Groups why is it so? the test string contains only one png
2. I used the same expression is a .net Regular expression validator and it doesn't validate correctly. I want the extensions in the groups to be allowed by a file input

Comment: What .NET validator did you use? I'd say it is broken. My installation accepts it just fine.

Comment: @Martin offcourse the regular expression validator. here is the markup `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" display="Dynamic" enableclientscript="true" controltovalidate="fileUpload" validationexpression="\.((jpg)|(gif)|(jpeg)|(png)|(doc)|(docx)|(pdf)|(zip)|(rar))$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>`

Comment: So yes, definitely double the backslash.

Comment: @Tim you mean `\\.jpg|gif|jpeg|png|doc|docx|pdf|zip|rar$` that too doesn't work for me

Comment: Why did you remove all parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Matches show as 2 Groups why is it so?

Because there are two groups. `((png))` is two groups. So is `((jpeg)|(png))`.

> I used the same expression is a .net Regular expression validator and it doesn't validate correctly.

Try a simpler regex. Grouping each extension separately is entirely pointless.

```
\.(jpg|gif|jpeg|png|doc|docx|pdf|zip|rar)$
```

Also think of making the regex case-insensitive, or it won't match upper-case extensions.

Comment: @Tomalak `Also think of making the regex case-insensitive,` do you have any idea how i could do it using the regular expression validator in .net validation controls

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Add `(?i)` to the start of the regex. This is called an in-line modifier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542042/how-to-use-inline-modifiers-in-c-regex

Comment: @Tomalak thanks btw could you put a regex to validate both filename and extension. i tried `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,20}+` but it accounts for `.png` in the extension also

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Wouldn't `"(?i)^[a-z0-9_]{5,20}\\.(jpg|gif|jpeg|png|doc|docx|pdf|zip|rar)$"` work? *PS: Tip for the next time: Think about your question and ask it **completely**. Having to add bits and bits of information in detective-Columbo-mode ("Oh, just one more question, sir!") is not very rewarding.*

Comment: @Tomalak you are genius and i didn't want to bug people with another question with the same idea or background. thanks again

Comment: @Deeptechtons: But that's not the point! ;-) Just ask a complete question right away next time. It's not a problem if it is complex or consists of several sub-questions, as long as it is specific. It's just frustrating to answer a question more in the comment thread than anywhere else, so try to avoid that in the future.

Answer (score 2):

1. Two groups are matching: The large one surrounding the entire alternation, and the smaller one surrounding the literal text `png`. You could remove the inner ones: `\.(jpg|gif|jpeg|png|doc|docx|pdf|zip|rar)$` works just as well.
2. Try doubling the backslash.

Comment: How do i qualify the Filename now i tried `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$` but it also accounts for `.` in the extension `.png` How do i validate filename to contain alphanumeric and underscores only leaving out the `.` or better said i want to validate both the filename and extension with same validation expression

Answer (score 1):

It has two groups because you have two sets of parenthesis. I've marked them with stars and spaces:

```
\. *(* (jpg)|(gif)|(jpeg)| *(* png *)* |(doc)|(docx)|(pdf)|(zip)|(rar) *)* $
```

Both of those groups match. You can make a set of parenthesis into a non-capturing group with `(?:`:

```
\.(?:(jpg)|(gif)|(jpeg)|(png)|(doc)|(docx)|(pdf)|(zip)|(rar))$
```

Your regex validates just fine on .NET. However note that in C#, backslashes are special characters inside strings. If you want to use a regular expression backslash you need to escape it:

```
var re = new Regex("\\.(?:(jpg)|(gif)|(jpeg)|(png)|(doc)|(docx)|(pdf)|(zip)|(rar))$");
```

Preferably, you should use a verbatim string and avoid the clunky double-escape:

```
var re = new Regex(@"\.(?:(jpg)|(gif)|(jpeg)|(png)|(doc)|(docx)|(pdf)|(zip)|(rar))$");
```

Comment: So the braces also account for a match with png?

Comment: please see my comment for your question in post#1

Comment: Yes. It captures the "png" portion into both groups. The inner one matches because that's exactly the string "png". The outer one matches because it matches one of all those options.