# How to use inline regex modifier in VB.NET

Tags: javascript, regex, vb.net, validation

I'm using jquery validate for client side email validation. 
Of course I also have server side validation and want to use the same regex as jquery does to validate the input on the server side.

I found this regex in the source of jquery validate:

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email
        email: function( value, element ) {
            // contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
            return this.optional(element) || /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i.test(value);
        },
```

Note the `/i`at the end of the regex to make the whole thing case insensitive.

I have a complex site with c# libraries Ánd VB libraries.

In both libraries I need to implement this email validation.

In C# I'm using this code:

```
Regex RegexEmailAddress = new Regex(@"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Note `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` at the end.

However, In my VB code I need a string that hold the regex pattern.

```
Public Const MAIL_REGEX As String = "^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$"
```

So far I coudn't find any working regex adjustment to make this regex case insensitive.

I tried adding `(?i)` in front of the string but it's logged as invalid regex when using it on my website.

also add `/i` at the end of the pattern gives an invalid regex.

**Update:** 
I tried another method with inline regex modifier I found in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641236/make-regular-expression-case-insensitive-in-asp-net-regularexpressionvalidator).

```
Case sensitive: ^[0-9]\s(lbs|kg|kgs)$

Case insensitive: (?i:^[0-9]\s(lbs|kg|kgs)$)
```

But it's also not working.

Here's the javascript error I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?i:^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$)/: Invalid group
```

**Update 2**

I'm using [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx)

```
RegularExpressionValidator rxvalEmail = new RegularExpressionValidator();
rxvalEmail.ID = "rxvalEmail";
rxvalEmail.ValidationExpression = SomeHelperInVB.MAIL_REGEX;
rxvalEmail.ControlToValidate = "txtEmail";
```

So how can I make my regex case insensitive using a inline regex modifier? Of any other sollution to solve this?

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542042/how-to-use-inline-modifiers-in-c-sharp-regex/3542055#3542055

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some information that might could help others:

I found out why the regex modifiers aren't working for RegularExpressionValidator when debugging the client side code used for validation.

The code below shows how client validation for regex is done using RegularExpressionValidator control:

```
function RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid(val) {
var value = ValidatorGetValue(val.controltovalidate);
if (ValidatorTrim(value).length == 0)
    return true;
var rx = new RegExp(val.validationexpression); // Error:  Invalid regular expression:....
var matches = rx.exec(value);
return (matches != null && value == matches[0]);
```

}

`new RegExp("pattern/i")` will be formatted as: `/pattern/i/`

and that's indeed no valid regex. The valid regex would be: /pattern/i

=> Conclusion: Modifiers can't work using RegularExpressionValidator. I'll probably write use CustomValidator control instead with custom server and client side code.

Another option would be to replace `[a-z]` with [a-zA-Z] in the used regex

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple console application and by using (?i) it works just fine:

```
Module Module1

Public Const MAIL_REGEX As String = "^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$"
Public Const MAIL_REGEX_I As String = "(?i)^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$"

Sub Main()
    Dim r_sensitive As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(MAIL_REGEX)
    Dim r_insensitive As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(MAIL_REGEX_I)

    ' Returns true
    Console.WriteLine("ok@ok.com: " + r_sensitive.IsMatch("ok@ok.com").ToString)
    ' Returns false
    Console.WriteLine("NOT_ok@ok.com: " + r_sensitive.IsMatch("NOT_ok@ok.com").ToString)

    ' Returns true
    Console.WriteLine("ok@ok.com: " + r_insensitive.IsMatch("ok@ok.com").ToString)
    ' Returns true
    Console.WriteLine("NOT_ok@ok.com: " + r_insensitive.IsMatch("NOT_ok@ok.com").ToString)

    Console.Read()
End Sub

End Module
```

**Update:**
OK, so you are using RegularExpressionValidator to do validation on both client and server. ..
Since the syntax is different between VB-RegEx and Javascript-Regex I'm not sure it's possible to do what you want. In VB you use (?i) in the beginning of the expression whereas in Javascript you need to add /i as a modifier when construction the expression (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Maybe you need to use another expression, which doesn't require a "case-insensitive modifier". This one is from Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})
```

Or, another option would be to replace [a-z] with [a-zA-Z] in your current expression.

Neither of the two expressions works when using Internationalized Domain Names, like "any.name@domännamn.se" (notice the "**ä**" in the domain name).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write this console app. However, I'm using RegularExpressionValidator (see my updated question) and there the modifiers doesn't seem to work...

Comment: The problem seems to be the client side validation. The regex passed to the ValidationExpression property of the RegularExpressionValidator object is used for both server side and client side validation. Javascript seems not to support inline modifiers...