# how to improve this short regularexpression to filter words

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using mvc3 and regular expressions on a field in a model and it works perfectly to prevent certain words from being typed; however I was wondering is there anyway that I can make RegularExpression words not case sensitive: I can block **www** but if a user types **Www** it goes through.

```
[RegularExpression("^((?!(www)).)*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character")]
```

I have other words in that regularexpression but no need to put them there any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a character class: `"^((?!([wW]{3})).)*$"`

Also, you can try to add an inline ?i modifier to your pattern to force it to be case insensitive.  See here: [How to use inline modifiers in C# regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542042/how-to-use-inline-modifiers-in-c-sharp-regex)