# Regular expression to validate A123456

Tags: regex

What is a suitable regular expression to validate that a string matches the format A123456

First letter must be a letter upper case or lower case then exactly 6 numeric numbers following it.

I'm using c# .net if that has any effect on the formatting.

Comment: Have you tried something? It's really basic.

Comment: Needed the answer in a rush and i was getting confused reading examples and figured the kind people here would help clarify for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to search for the following pattern:

- (`(?i)`) - [*Modifiers*] Case-insensitive
- (`^`) - Begin

  - (`[a-z]`) - A single letter
  - (`\d{6}`) - Digits 0-9 with length of 6
- ( `$`) - End

Resulting regular expression: `(?i)^[a-z]\d{6}$`

```
Regex alpha1numeric6Pattern = new Regex(@"(?i)^[a-z]\d{6}$");
```

See it in action: [3aaeea6ad8ce3e4ab9ac@csharppad](http://csharppad.com/gist/3aaeea6ad8ce3e4ab9ac).

Comment: It can be, I just wanted to let you know about the [modifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3542048/1762224).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]\d{6}$
```

You would benefit from a quick read at http://www.regularexpressions.info

Answer (score 1):

This would do what you are after: `^[A-Za-z]\d{6}$`. An example can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/xL9nI3/1).