# Extract string from multiple line string

Tags: powershell

I want to extract the content between `abc {` and `}`.

```
$s = 'abc {
    123
}'
$s -match 'abc {(.*?)' # true
$s -match 'abc {(.*?)}' # false, expect true
```

However, it seems it doesn't do multiple line match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` will only match on newline characters when you perform a regex operation in `SingleLine` mode.

You can add a [regex option at the start of your pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542042/how-to-use-inline-modifiers-in-c-sharp-regex/3542048) with `(?[optionflags])`:

```
$s -match 'abc {(.*?)}'       # $False, `.` doesn't match on newline
$s -match '(?s)abc {(.*?)}'   # $True, (?s) makes `.` match on newline
```