# Problem facing while matching regex pattern to a list of names

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have a list of names for which I am trying to implement proper casing- the list of names are as follows

- DR. JOHN GROVE WHITE
- RONALD MCDONALD
- GORDON SAINT JOHN
- ARTHUR STEVENS
- GAIL VAN STOLK
- ANWAR AL-SADAT
- SYMS III, ROGER
- ROGER SYMS V

For the above list I have implemented regex pattern. The regex pattern are working properly when i put then on regex testing websites but it is not working in code

```
Regex.IsMatch(value, @"(/^(van|von|der|la|d[aeio]|d[ao]s|dit)[\s,]*$/i)")
```

The above is not matching when i pass value as van in code

```
Regex.IsMatch(value, @"(/(^|\s)+(Mc|[DO]\'|St\.|St[\.]?[\s]|Dewolf)/i)")
```

The above is not working when i pass value as Mcdonald

```
Regex.IsMatch(value, @"(/(^|\s*)(Mac)(allist|arth|b|c(allu|art|ask|l|r|ull)|d|f|g|i(nn|nty|saa|v)|kinn|kn|l(a|ea|eo)|m|na[mu]|n[ei]|ph|q|ra|sw|ta|w)/i)")
```

The above regex is not matching when i pass value as Macdonald

I am not able to find out is there any issue in regex.Please help me out for the above.Thanks in advance

Comment: The above regex patterns is for multiple surname,name,ordianal scenario from which van,Macdonald are some of valid values

Comment: Try it without using the `/i` and without the start anchor `^` for example `Regex.IsMatch("van test", @"(\b(van|von|der|la|d[aeio]|d[ao]s|dit)[\s,]*)");` See this page for case insensitive https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_IgnoreCase

Comment: thanks it worked for above regex ,please do help for other pattern too

Comment: Did you try the same apprach for the other patterns?

Comment: I did these to Regex.IsMatch(value, @"(\b(i{3}|i{1,2}v?|v?i{1,2})[\s,]*)" . These regex pattern is to match ordinal Ordinal suffixes (I - VIII only) in name. for example name like Roger Syms V , but it not worked. others worked, thanks

Comment: That is because you are trying to match at least 1 or 2 times a `i` before the optional `v` Try `\b(i{3}|i{0,2}v|vi{1,2})[\s,]*` If you want to match roman numerals, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression

Comment: The above regex for roman literal is also matching with alphabet 'v'. i dont want this to happen . is there any way to avoid the same so that it matched only with roman literals not with any alphabets

Comment: Are you using the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option? See this page how to enable and disable ignore case inline https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542042/how-to-use-inline-modifiers-in-c-sharp-regex/3542048